# Drop-down menu in iOS alert

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu, alert

I'm trying to set labels to certain areas of an app dynamically so that some of them show while others are hidden. I have an alert that prompts for text to fill these labels with, but I know the options in advance and would like to only allow the user to choose certain options.
Is there a way to have a drop-down menu of options in an iOS alert rather than a simple text input? Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a dropdown menu but you can have multiple buttons, one for every option.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"title" message: @"message" 
delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @[@"option1", @"option2", 
@"option3"], nil];
```

Comment: This is the way. There's not even a native drop down menu style control in iOS. The alternative is to use your own custom modal view.

Comment: If you have many options, you can display a modal view controller containing a UITableView with all your options.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need:

@[@"option1", @"option2", @"option3"], nil

Use simple strings instead:

@"option1", @"option2", @"option3", nil